# Serial converter - cat /dev/ttyUSB0 hangs on open

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and attached a Garmin data cable. The device gets recognized

```
[17718.502138] USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[17718.502181] pl2303 2-1:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[17718.513416] usb 2-1: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[17718.513443] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[17718.513446] pl2303: Prolific PL2303 USB to serial adaptor driver
```

... but when I do a `strace cat /dev/ttyUSB0` it hangs on the open part and does not continue any more>

```
open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILEC
```

If I do the same on Ubuntu 12.04 it stops on `fread(" ... ")` which is okay, as there is currently no data comming in at this port.

I am not sure if it is just a different configuration of the system or an driver related problem. How can I track this down further? Unfortunately I can not update the old Ubuntu 11.04 system for different reasons at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. Have a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/661321

A workaround seems to be to run the following commands after connecting the USB cable:

```
modprobe -r pl2303
modprobe pl2303
```